# How to modify the value of a model sent to another class without affecting the original model

Tags: c#, wpf, class, model

```cs
    public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private MyEnum _myEnumValue;
    
        public MyEnum MyEnumValue
        {
            get => _myEnumValue;
            set
            {
                if (value == _myEnumValue) return;
                _myEnumValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    //OnPropertyChanged things
    }
```

```cs
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        private MyModel _myModelVariable;
        public MyModel MyModelVariable
        {
            get=>_myModelVariable;
            set{_myModelVariable = value; OnPropertyChanged();} 
        }
    
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            MyModelVariable = new();
            MyModelVariable.MyEnumValue = MyEnum.Enum1;
        }
    
        public void OptionsButton()
        {
            _windowManager.ShowDialogAsync(new EditViewModel(MyModelVariable));
        }   
    }
```

```cs
    public class EditViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private MyModel _localModel;
    
        public EditClass(MyModel myModel)
        {
            _localModel = myModel
        }
    
        public MyModel LocalModel
        {
            get=>_localModel;
            set
            {
                _localModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    
        public void OkButton()
        {
            // sending LocalModel to Main View Model with EventAggregator
        }
    
        public void CancelButton()
        {
            CloseWindow();
        }
    }
```

**The given code is simulated from original code**.
In my WPF application, I am using Caliburn Micro and working with view models. On one of my screens, the user presses the options button to update values. When the button is pressed, a new window opens, and this window is controlled by the EditViewModel. I create the window by using "new" and open it with IWindowManager. While opening it, I send my original model. In the EditViewModel, I assign the original model to a local variable and perform operations on it. The Selected value in the ComboBox on the front end is bound. When the user changes it, I also change the local variable. If the user presses OK, I send the new values to MainViewModel using EventAggregator. If they press Cancel, I close the window without doing anything.

Problem: When the user changes the value on the EditViewModel's front end, the value of the original model in MainViewModel changes as well. This is a probable situation since it sees the original value as a reference, but I don't want this to happen. I have tried solutions like cloning and copying, but I couldn't resolve it. What are your suggestions?

Comment: Solutions go in answers, not edits to the question. And they certainly don't go in block quote syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your Model reference `public`, are you binding to them? Are you aware that the Model must not be exposed to the View?
And why is your View Model concerned with button events and opening and closing windows? Are you aware that the View Model must not actively interact with the View? Do not do this. Aside of adding extra and unnecessary complexity you allow the UI logic to bleed into application logic. We use various design patterns and design principles to avoid exactly this case.
Dialogs are *always* managed in the view.

You must ensure to edit a copy of the original instance. once the edit process has completed you update the original instance.
The key is to add an intermediate data layer to the editable object to enable temporary data states (an edit flow like edit-and-commit) and data rollback.

I recommend implementing the `IEditableObject` interface.

The following example shows how to edit data with the support to commit or cancel temporary edits. In case of cancellation, the object's data changes are reverted.
The example also shows how to correctly handle dialogs and the application Model.

**ChildViewModel.cs**
The editable data object.

```cs
public class ChildViewModel : IEditableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private class ChildViewModelEditableDataModel : ICloneable
  {
    public ChildViewModelEditableDataModel()
    {
    }

    // Copy constructor for creating a deep copy
    public ChildViewModelEditableDataModel(ChildViewModelEditableDataModel myClassDataModelToCopy)
    {
      this.NumericValue = myClassDataModelToCopy.NumericValue;
      this.TextValue = myClassDataModelToCopy.TextValue;
    }

    public int NumericValue { get; set; } 
    public string TextValue { get; set; }

    // Create a shallow copy
    public ChildViewModelEditableDataModel Clone() => (ChildViewModelEditableDataModel)MemberwiseClone();

    // Create a deep copy
    public ChildViewModelEditableDataModel DeepClone() => new ChildViewModelEditableDataModel(this);

    object ICloneable.Clone() => Clone();
  }

  public ChildViewModel()
  {
    this.CurrentDataModel = new ChildViewModelEditableDataModel();
    this.BackupDataModel = this.CurrentDataModel.DeepClone();
  }

  public void BeginEdit() => this.BackupDataModel = this.CurrentDataModel;
  public void CancelEdit() => this.CurrentDataModel = this.BackupDataModel;
  public void EndEdit() => OnDataChanged();

  protected virtual void OnDataChanged() 
    => this.DataChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

  public event EventHandler DataChanged;

  public int NumericValue 
  { 
    get => this.CurrentDataModel.NumericValue;
    set => this.CurrentDataModel.NumericValue = value; 
  }

  public string TextValue
  {
    get => this.CurrentDataModel.TextValue;
    set => this.CurrentDataModel.TextValue = value;
  }

  private ChildViewModelEditableDataModel CurrentDataModel { get; set; }
  private ChildViewModelEditableDataModel BackupDataModel { get; set; }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ChildViewModel ChildViewModel { get; }

  // Do not expose the Model to the View
  private SomeModelClass SomeModelClass { get; }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.ChildViewModel = new ChildViewModel();

    // React to committed data changes of an edit procedure
    this.ChildViewModel.DataChanged += OnChildViewModelDataChanged;

    this.SomeModelClass = new SomeModelClass();
  }

  private void OnChildViewModelDataChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Update the Model with the modified data (example).
    // Make sure to not pass the view model instance.
    // Instead pasas a model type that is defined in the Model.
    this.SomeModelClass.Update(this.ChildViewModel.TextValue, this.ChildViewModel.NumericValue);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static RoutedCommand ShowEditDialogCommand = new RoutedCommand(nameof(ShowEditDialogCommand), typeof(MainWindow));

  public MaainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    var showEditDialogCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(ShowEditDialogCommand, ExecuteShowEditDialogCommand, CanExecuteShowEditDialogCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(showEditDialogCommandBinding);

    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
  }

  private void CanExecuteShowEditDialogCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => e.CanExecute = e.Parameter is IEditableObject;
  
  private void ExecuteShowEditDialogCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    IEditableObject editableData = (IEditableObject)e.Parameter;
    var editDialog = new Window() { DataContext = editableData };
    editableData.BeginEdit();
    bool? dialogResult = editDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (dialogResult == true)
    {
      editableData.EndEdit();
    }
    else
    {
      editableData.CancelEdit();
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding TextValue}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding NumericValue}" />

    <!-- Trigger the dialog to edit the data -->
    <Button Content="Edit"
            Command="{x:Static MainWindow.ShowEditDialogCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```